# gstreamer convert mp3 to wav

Tags: mp3, gstreamer, file-conversion, wave

I'm trying to convert an mp3 file to wav with gstreamer. Here's the pipeline:

gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=audio.mp3 ! audio/mpeg ! mpg123audiodec ! wavenc ! filesink location=audio.wav

Also, I'd like the output to be 24 bit/48kHz

I get this error:

ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0: Filter caps do not completely specify the output format

There was another similar thread that I saw here and tried to comment, but I had to have 50 points or whatever;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make use of the bins to make your life easier. I came up with this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=in.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! \
audio/x-raw,format=S24LE,rate=48000 ! wavenc ! filesink location=out.wav
```

Which gives me this result:

```
$ file out.wav
out.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 24 bit, stereo 48000 Hz
```